# Git - exclude remote branch folder when switching to the other one

Tags: git

Let's imagine that Git Repository has few remote branches and we can switch / checkout between each of them.

The structure of repository is as follows:

```
GIT_REPOSITORY
-- .git
-- /remote-branch-A
-- /remote-branch-B
-- /remote-branch-C
```

When a developer wants to provide some fixes within **/remote-branch-A** and then commit the changes, other remote branch folders should be excluded from commit.

So, my question is - how to exclude other remote branch folders from commit when you're inside a specific one branch?

Example:

```
git checkout remote-branch-A
git add . --> when adding all changes, I want to exlude remote-branch-B and remote-branch-C

git commit -m "Fixes message"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/remote-branch-A
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Changes to branches are individual anyway unless you rebase or merge them.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote branch folders"? Are you using [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)? (Git doesn't put branches into separate folders by default, and if you're using `git worktree` each working copy should be isolated.)

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout remote-branch-A and add a .gitignore file that contains the folders for remote-branch-B and remote-branch-C. Afterwards you do the same for the other two branches so the branch-specific .gitignore file will always tell git to ignore changes in the other two directories.